# GUI of certain OpenGL/QT programs do not correctly show orientation/scaling

Tags: 16.04, graphics, gtk, qt, opengl

In Ubuntu 16.04 on Intel i7-6700K and Intel HD 530 with Unity, Like [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDiYp.png), certain OpenGL/QT based programs show GUI with too large buttons, and certain areas are omitted. The programs with the problems are presumed to be mostly based on OpenGL and QT, like Schrodinger Maestro, PyMOL, and other scientific visualization and modelling programs. What can be the problem, and what should be done to resolve the problem?
Thank you in advance. (For anyone with enough reps, please embed the image and remove this text.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem with the DPI settings on QT.
in order to resolve this, add
export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0
to ~/.bashrc
or execute with
QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0 ./program
every time you use the program in the terminal.
Or if you want to resolve this problem with one program  only, add
alias progo='QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0 /path/to/program'
(change progo to a separate name every time you add this)
in ~/.bashrc